# How to get the current Axes.View after using rotate3d interaction in MATLAB appdesigner?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

I'm using MATLAB R2021b appdesigner to design a UI . And my request is that I want to **get the current axes view (azimuth & elevation data)** after rotating my plot via rotate3d interation tool using my mouse. I have checked the related documentation and found that the following code worked well in the script form:

```
function demo_mbd2
% Listen to rotate events
surf(peaks);
h = rotate3d;
h.ActionPreCallback = @myprecallback;
h.ActionPostCallback = @mypostcallback;
h.Enable = 'on';

function myprecallback(obj,evd)
disp('A rotation is about to occur.');

function mypostcallback(obj,evd)
newView = round(evd.Axes.View);
msgbox(sprintf('The new view is [%d %d].',newView));
```

However, I have no idea of how to embed it in the **appdesigner** environment. For example, I'm not aware of the right form of callback function - neither `mypostcallback(app, obj, evd)` nor `mypostcallback(obj, evd)` worked.

I haven't learned so much about call back functions yet I'm in desperate need of solving this specific problem. Could anyone lend me a hand? Are there any feasible ways to use the previous codes, or do we have any other solutions?

Huge thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean they "didn't work"?  Did it cause an error (if so please [edit] and quote it) or just not enter the callback function?

Comment: An error occurred. However, I have solved this problem. It seems I should use `h.ActionPostCallback = @app.mypostcallback;` and `function mypostcallback(app, obj, evd)` in the appdesigner environment. Still, thank you for your comment.